# Python packages for finance and accounting?

Tags: library, python, finance, accounting

I would like to automate depreciation methods and SOX checks in my accounting process. Before I start hard coding the formulas, are there any python packages that I can use for finance/accounting to help with the process? I searched the anaconda and pip repositories but could not find much for accounting. If you know any packages, just answer here and I will appreciate it!

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I have no personal experience with any of these, but the following might be relevant:

[accounting](https://pypi.org/project/accounting/)
[Finance-Python](https://pypi.org/project/Finance-Python/)
[Financial](https://pypi.org/project/Financial/)
[pyfolio](https://pypi.org/project/pyfolio/)
[finmarketpy](https://github.com/cuemacro/finmarketpy)
[ffn](https://pypi.org/project/ffn/)
[Quantlib](https://www.quantlib.org/)